# Spacing between each item and each row

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add space between each items in the column has well i want add a little space between each row,i had tried padding ,divider and applying null it is'nt working in my case.

I have added divider height to listview has in below code but not working out

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="total and comment section" />
    </LinearLayout>

and items layout is which displays items in the listview

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set paddings or margins to each row of list view in custom ArrayAdapter?

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter - pretty simple tutorial about custom adapters
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html - comprehensive tutorial about working with ListView

Answer (score 0):

```
        for space in row you want to set dividerHeight of listview 
        and for column 
        you want to set android:layout_marginLeft  for right text view

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want set a fixed width for each column ,if the data length is more it should truncate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:divider="#00000000"
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
```